# pyinstaller not integrating a cairo.Context properly

Tags: python, pyinstaller, cairo

I'm trying to prepare an executable for delivery using pyinstaller.

I've installed and run pyinstaller as follows:

```
sudo pip install pyinstaller
```

everything looks good after the install, so I proceed to run the tool on my application

```
sudo pyinstaller App.py --onefile
```

this produces an executable in the ./dist folder as expected.  When I move this file to the normal runtime folder where the app works correctly when run from python source (e.g. sudo ./App.py a b c), the app launches and is clearly working in most ever way (it is reading data and writing files, etc., however the graphics for some of the dynamic drawing isn't getting rendered.

On the console where it was launched from, the following error is shown, many times:

```
TypeError: Couldn't find foreign struct converter for 'cairo.Context'
```

However, this package has been installed, along with a similar package, prior to running the pyinstaller:

```
sudo apt install python3-gi-cairo
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
python3-gi-cairo is already the newest version (3.36.0-1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 6 not upgraded.
```

Also, pyinstaller produces these following lines while building the executable:

```
26841 INFO: Analyzing hidden import 'python-gi-cairo'
26841 ERROR: Hidden import 'python-gi-cairo' not found
```

Why isn't pyinstaller seeing the python-gi-cairo package?

Any ideas for what I can try next?

Comment: Please, for the love of Pete, [don't ever run `sudo pip ...`](https://pages.charlesreid1.com/dont-sudo-pip/). Pip has been modified to save you from yourself by redirecting the install to `/usr/local/`, so that you don't blow up your distro's packaging. But it's still worth heeding the warning it emits whenever you do that. Either use a virtual environment (in which case, `python3 -m pip install ...` or `pip install ...`), or install to your user `site-packages` with either of the same two commands from _outside_ of a venv. Why do you need `pyinstaller` in `/usr/local/bin/`?

Comment: Thanks for that feedback, it's good information. pip didn't need to be run as sudo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a duplicate question, to this one, and could be closed or removed.
[missing dependency after running pyinstaller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73981704/missing-dependency-after-running-pyinstaller)

The answer to the question, is also answered in the above referenced link.