# Pyinstaller not building the cairo.Context properly

Tags: matplotlib, pyinstaller, cairo

NOTE: I've edited this description and title to include new information during the debugging process.

I have a python application that needs to be converted to an executable.  The application draws graphics using the python-gi-cairo package, among others.

The following is an error message in the terminal window, after launching the application:

```
TypeError: Couldn't find foreign struct converter for 'cairo.Context'
```

I've already posted separately about making a minimal drawing app that I can test pyinstaller parameters with.  Here is a link to that post:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73981704/missing-dependency-after-running-pyinstaller?noredirect=1#comment130629339_73981704
```

here is the evms.spec file:

```
# -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-


block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(
    ['evms.py'],
    pathex=[],
    binaries=[],
    datas=[],
    hiddenimports=['matplotlib', 'python-gi-cairo'],
    hookspath=[],
    hooksconfig={},
    runtime_hooks=[],
    excludes=[],
    win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
    win_private_assemblies=False,
    cipher=block_cipher,
    noarchive=False,
)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data, cipher=block_cipher)

exe = EXE(
    pyz,
    a.scripts,
    a.binaries,
    a.zipfiles,
    a.datas,
    [],
    name='evms',
    debug=False,
    bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
    strip=False,
    upx=True,
    upx_exclude=[],
    runtime_tmpdir=None,
    console=True,
    disable_windowed_traceback=False,
    argv_emulation=False,
    target_arch=None,
    codesign_identity=None,
    entitlements_file=None,
)
```

Comment: Pyinstaller should automatically include that file if it is necessary. Please share the spec file you pass to pyinstaller. In your spec file, try setting hiddenimports=["matplotlib"].

Comment: not sure the best way to include that information. I'll edit the post and include the file there....

Comment: Perfect. Try setting hiddenimports=["matplotlib"].

Comment: Thank you. It built the executable, however the instrument graphics aren't getting rendered, but everything else is working correctly (from what I can tell).  The error reported in the terminal window that launches the app is: "TypeError: Couldn't find foreign struct converter for 'cairo.Context' "

Comment: I don't know anything about cairo, by try setting hiddenimports=["matplotlib", "pycairo"]. Just a guess.

Comment: updated spec file after another couple tries, resulting in: 'sudo pyinstaller --onefile --hidden-import matplotlib --hidden-import cairo evms.py'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out there was a missing import statement, (import cairo) which when added, enabled the pyinstaller to build an executable that works great.  I'm not sure why the .py version of the application was working without that import.

```
import gi
gi.require_version("Gtk", "3.0")
from gi.repository import Gtk as gtk
from gi.repository import Gdk as gdk
import cairo
from gi.repository import GLib
```